# Making $R(x)=\frac{x^3+8x^2+18x+15}{x+5}$ continuous from $x = -5$ point

Tags: calculus, continuity

The function $R(x)=\frac{x^3+8x^2+18x+15}{x+5}$ is not defined at the point $x = -5$. How should it be defined to make it continuous at this point.

I'm pretty sure you have to factor the top but for some reason I'm having a hard time with this problem.

Please Help.

Comment: If you've had synthetic division or polynomial division, you will be able to find $ \ x^3 + 8x^2 + 18x + 15 = (x+5) (x^2 + 3x + 3) \ $ .

Comment: And @RecklessReckoner's comment shows that $\lim_{x \to -5, x \neq -5} R(x) = 13$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where *polynomial long division* comes in handy.

We want to remove the removable singularity at $x = -5$, so we test to determine the quotient when dividing the numerator by the factor $(x + 5)$.

Doing so gives us: $$x^3 + 8x^2 + 18x + 15 = (x+5) (x^2 + 3x + 3)$$

This gives us $$\frac{x^3+8x^2+18x+15}{x+5} \implies  \frac{(x+5)(x^2 + 3x + 3)}{(x + 5)} = x^2 + 3x + 3$$

which is continuous at $x = -5$.

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple way to factor those types of problems. For some reason it just wasn't coming to me. Thank you so much man

Comment: You're welcome. The clue here is that we're wanting to cancel the $(x + 1)$ in the denominator, since it is zero when $x = -5$. So the natural choice to test as a factor in the numerator is $(x + 5)$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know polynomial division, you can use the fact that you already know one of the factors is $x+5$ to find the other factor:
$$(x+5)(ax^2+bx+c)=x^3+8x^2+18x+15$$
Start with the smallest power of $x$ ($0$): $$5c=15\ \to \ c = 3$$
Now on to multiples of $x$:
$$cx+5bx=3x+5bx=18x\ \to \ b=3$$
And at last:
$$5ax^2+bx^2=8x^2 \ \to \ a=1$$